# Javascript Html Tree

Tags: javascript, tree

I am struggling with a recursive function that should layout an HTML tree in javascript. I'm just not sure how to pull the information I need into a JSX for display in a ReactJS component. Unfortunately, this is as far as I can get on the function.  Can someone please give me a hand or point me to a tutorial on how to do this?  Thanks!

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import API from "../../../api";

    export const Messenger = (props) => {
        const buildTree = (obj,level) => {    
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty("children")){
                console.log(`${level} ===> ${obj.foldername}`)
                return
            }
            for(let i=0;i<obj.children.length;i++){                        
                buildTree(obj.children[i],level+1)  
            }                              
        }
        const fetchData = async () => {
            let resp = await API.get(`flddata?token=${sessionStorage.getItem("token")}`)
            let data = buildTree(resp.data.data, 0)
        }
        useEffect(() => fetchData(), []);
        return (<div>Will Put The Tree Here!</div>)
    }
```

I am consuming the `data` object of the following JSON response from API:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "recordid": "",
    "foldername": "Mailboxes",
    "isdraggable": false,
    "isdroppable": false,
    "issystem": true,
    "children": [
      {
        "recordid": "d52d1c41-657a-11eb-9664-e454e88b0aea",
        "usrdataid": "85f15f52-3a3c-11eb-8dd8-e454e88b0aea",
        "parentid": "",
        "foldername": "Inbox",
        "isdraggable": null,
        "isdroppable": 0,
        "issystem": 1,
        "position": 0,
        "active": 1
      },
      {
        "recordid": "fdae991d-657a-11eb-9664-e454e88b0aea",
        "usrdataid": "85f15f52-3a3c-11eb-8dd8-e454e88b0aea",
        "parentid": "",
        "foldername": "Sent",
        "isdraggable": null,
        "isdroppable": 0,
        "issystem": 1,
        "position": 1,
        "active": 1
      },
      {
        "recordid": "fdaf38ad-657a-11eb-9664-e454e88b0aea",
        "usrdataid": "85f15f52-3a3c-11eb-8dd8-e454e88b0aea",
        "parentid": "",
        "foldername": "Archived",
        "isdraggable": null,
        "isdroppable": 0,
        "issystem": 1,
        "position": 2,
        "active": 1
      },
      {
        "recordid": "fdafa2bd-657a-11eb-9664-e454e88b0aea",
        "usrdataid": "85f15f52-3a3c-11eb-8dd8-e454e88b0aea",
        "parentid": "",
        "foldername": "Deleted",
        "isdraggable": null,
        "isdroppable": 0,
        "issystem": 1,
        "position": 3,
        "active": 1
      },
      {
        "recordid": "fdb00601-657a-11eb-9664-e454e88b0aea",
        "usrdataid": "85f15f52-3a3c-11eb-8dd8-e454e88b0aea",
        "parentid": "",
        "foldername": "Personal",
        "isdraggable": null,
        "isdroppable": 0,
        "issystem": 1,
        "position": 4,
        "active": 1,
        "children": [
          {
            "recordid": "63375438-6643-11eb-9664-e454e88b0aea",
            "usrdataid": "85f15f52-3a3c-11eb-8dd8-e454e88b0aea",
            "parentid": "fdb00601-657a-11eb-9664-e454e88b0aea",
            "foldername": "Dr. Cortes",
            "isdraggable": 1,
            "isdroppable": 0,
            "issystem": 1,
            "position": 5,
            "active": 1,
            "children": [
              {
                "recordid": "87f6e2f9-6647-11eb-9664-e454e88b0aea",
                "usrdataid": "85f15f52-3a3c-11eb-8dd8-e454e88b0aea",
                "parentid": "63375438-6643-11eb-9664-e454e88b0aea",
                "foldername": "Angela Lopez",
                "isdraggable": 1,
                "isdroppable": 0,
                "issystem": 1,
                "position": 6,
                "active": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I was able to figure out how to generate the tree I needed.

```
const FolderTree = ({data}) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {data.map((node, ndx) => {
                return (
                    <li id={node.id} key={ndx}>
                        {node.foldername}
                        {node.children && <FolderTree data={node.children} />}
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```